# postgreSQL- Count for value between previous month start date and end date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table as follows

```
user_id   date         month  year   visiting_id
 123      11-04-2017   APRIL  2017   4500
 123      12-05-2017   MAY    2017   4567
 123      13-05-2017   MAY    2017   4568
 123      17-05-2017   MAY    2017   4569
 123      22-05-2017   MAY    2017   4570
 123      11-06-2017   JUNE   2017   4571
 123      12-06-2017   JUNE   2017   4572
```

I want to calculate the visiting count for the current month and last month at the monthly level as follows:

```
user_id   month   year   visit_count_this_month  visit_count_last_month
 123      APRIL   2017               1                      0
 123      MAY     2017               4                      1
 123      JUNE    2017               2                      4
```

I was able to calculate visit_count_this_month using the following query

```
SELECT v.user_id, v.month, v.year, 
       SUM(is_visit_this_month) as visit_count_this_month
FROM
   (SELECT user_id, date, month, year,
        CASE WHEN  TO_CHAR(date, 'MM/YYYY') = TO_CHAR(date, 'MM/YYYY') 
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 
        END as is_visit_this_month
   FROM visits
   GROUP BY user_id, date, month, year
   HAVING user_id = 123) v 
GROUP BY v.user_id, v.month, v.year
```

However, I'm stuck with calculating visit_count_last_month. Similar to this, I also want to calculate visit_count_last_2months.

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there are values for every month, you can get the counts per month first and use `lag` to get the previous month's values per user.

```
SELECT T.*
,COALESCE(LAG(visits,1) OVER(PARTITION BY USER_ID ORDER BY year,mth),0) as last_month_visits
,COALESCE(LAG(visits,2) OVER(PARTITION BY USER_ID ORDER BY year,mth),0) as last_2_month_visits
FROM (
SELECT user_id, extract(month from date) as mth, year, COUNT(*) as visits
FROM visits
GROUP BY user_id, extract(month from date), year
) T
```

If there can be missing months, it is best to generate all months within a specified timeframe and `left join` ing the table on to that. (This example shows it for all the months in 2017).

```
select user_id,yr,mth,visits
,coalesce(lag(visits,1) over(PARTITION BY USER_ID ORDER BY yr,mth),0) as last_month_visits
,coalesce(lag(visits,2) OVER(PARTITION BY USER_ID ORDER BY yr,mth),0) as last_2_month_visits
from (select u.user_id,extract(year from d.dt) as yr, extract(month from d.dt) as mth,count(v.visiting_id) as visits
      from generate_series(date '2017-01-01', date '2017-12-31',interval '1 month') d(dt)
      cross join (select distinct user_id from visits) u
      left join visits v on extract(month from v.dt)=extract(month from d.dt) and extract(year from v.dt)=extract(year from d.dt) and u.user_id=v.user_id
      group by u.user_id,extract(year from d.dt), extract(month from d.dt)
      ) t
```

Comment: I get this error: "function lag(bigint, integer, integer) does not exist" :(

Comment: Wow! +1 more forward thinking! Next question was in my mind was how to handle the missing months count. Actually, I should be generating this series from the joining date of the user(which is in another table) to the current date. Let me try that. Thank you so much for you help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a LATERAL JOIN like this:

```
SELECT user_id, month, year, COUNT(*) as visit_count_this_month, visit_count_last_month
FROM visits v
    CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
        SELECT COUNT(*) as visit_count_last_month
        FROM visits
        WHERE user_id = v.user_id
            AND date = (CAST(v.date AS date) - interval '1 month')
  ) l
GROUP BY user_id, month, year, visit_count_last_month;
```

SQLFiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/393c8/2